# Filtering a collection by an async result

Tags: c#, linq, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var loudDogs = dogs.Where(async d => await d.IsYappyAsync);
```

The "IsYappyAsync" property would return a `Task<bool>`.

Obviously this isn't supported, so instead I've built an extension method called WhereAsync.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> WhereAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, Task<bool>> predicate)
{
    var results = new List<T>();
    var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var task = predicate.Invoke(item);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    var predicateResults = await Task.WhenAll<bool>(tasks);

    var counter = 0;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var predicateResult = predicateResults.ElementAt(counter);

        if (predicateResult)
            results.Add(item);

        counter++;
    }

    return results.AsEnumerable();
}
```

This probably isn't the best approach, but I'm at a loss for something better. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you're after and it depends on whether you want the results drip fed to you as they're available or whether you're happy to have them all in one bang.
The way you've implemented your method gives it all in one bang - which is fine.

A shorter implementation could be

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> WhereAsync2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, Task<bool>> predicate)
{
    var itemTaskList = items.Select(item=> new {Item = item, PredTask = predicate.Invoke(item)}).ToList();
    await Task.WhenAll(itemTaskList.Select(x=>x.PredTask));
    return itemTaskList.Where(x=>x.PredTask.Result).Select(x=>x.Item);
}
```

1. It builds a list of an anonymous type where the type contains the item and the Task.
2. It then waits for all of the tasks to complete.
3. It then goes through that list from (1) and picks out the items that had a true result from the Task.

The other advantage is that you get rid of all of that counter and `ElementAt()` stuff.  Either way still builds a complete List for the items in the given Enumerable...

**Aside**: *You could investigate something like Rx if you wanted the results via an `IObservable<T>` instead.  The result wouldn't even be async Task - it would just be an IObservable.*

Comment: This is nice, bookmarked for later usage, thank you

Comment: I don't like this approach. Using `.Result` is most likely never the correct answer.

Comment: Thabks for the comment all these years later The tasks are known to be complete, so it's safe in this context. I appreciate that's a distinction often missed by many, but it's OK in this context. (eventually, somewhere in the code, even if it's not your code but something invoked by the async/await state machine, something is calling .Result to actually get the result)

Comment: Agree with @ElMac. Using `.Result` is usually a code smell, and in this case it certainly is. It is definitely not "safe" or "OK in this context". You have made the code synchronous as `.Result` blocks. You are also ignoring the return of `await WhenAll` which is also a code smell. The result of `await WhenAll` is _exactly_ what you should be performing the `Where` on.

Comment: @neo, Thanks for the comment. `.Result` is synchronous, and blocks if there's no result yet.  We *know* that every single one of these Tasks has a result. That's what awaiting `Task.WhenAll` is doing in this code.  It is "OK in this context" - sorry you disagree.  As it turns out, I'd probably write this differently all these years later (and would've at least deliberately noted via comment that .Result was intentional), but it's not *broken*
Using Tasks that return an anonymous type, with a bool member, would allow for the filtering you suggest and is probably nicer overall.

Comment: We agree on what `.Result` does it seems, but to make the code synchronous defeats the point of asynchronous programming - this isn't "OK". That's why there's no async `Where` in the BCL. It's inherently counterfactual. That's the code smell. Re my other point, I've put code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aV5xFk). Ignoring return of `await WhenAll` is bad practice. This doesn't fix the aforementioned code smell, but you can achieve your solution without ignoring it (`WhereAsync3` in my Fiddle). In fact you can go further and not use it at all. Just use `Task.Run` (`WhereAsync4` in my Fiddle).